# what does value of t test mean?

Tags: distributions, t-test

I have two distribution of one variable and I've used t test to find how much they are significantly different. But I'm not very familiar with this test and don't know what does this values mean? is there any threshold to be sure the two distribution are different?

Comment: This is way too unclear and broad. Have you actually run the test? There are more than one value reported in t-tests and by "what does value of t test" which one do you actually mean? Also, you mentioned two distributions but are they from independent groups or are the paired somehow? If this question is not supplemented with more specific details I'm afraid it'd be closed for being unclear.

Comment: I used the formula used in http://www.socialresearchmethods.net/kb/stat_t.php to compute t-test. actually they are precision of two related process on one dataset. Sorry if my question does not make sense. I'm novice in this field.

Comment: What are the values about whose interpretation you are unsure?

Comment: Acctually when I use that formula I got some values like 0.3 or 1.5 so I'm not sure if I can say those two variables have same distribution or not based these values